# Is Flutter Web caching "flutter.js" in the browser cache storage, even after page reloads?

Tags: flutter

After deploying many builds, there is a problem in my app: Icon buttons are clickable but not visible. But if I navigate using Incognito mode(Chrome) the app works fine.

I found in the browser Cache Storage that there is a file saved 4 months ago, called `flutter.js`. So seems I have to tell all users to remove their cache each time I make a new build(even changing version number in `pubspec.yaml` and using `flutter clean` command).

[image]

My index.html(using Flutter 3.13.9):

Inside the `<head>` tag

`<script src="flutter.js" defer></script>`

And inside the `<body>` tag

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      var loading = document.querySelector('#loading');
      loading.textContent = "Loading entrypoint...";
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          loading.textContent = "Initializing engine...";
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            loading.textContent = "Running app...";
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Is there a way to update `flutter.js`(or any cached file that breaks the app) once the user presses the refresh button in the browser?

***Note***: Tried adding this line but didn't fix

```
_flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        entrypointUrl: "main.dart.js?v=" + serviceWorkerVersion,
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix it by using this workaround:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63500#issuecomment-1625251293

Icon buttons are visible now, and `flutter.js` seems to be updated.
I will wait for a better fix though.

[image]